# Why tagged pointers exists

Tags: pointers, memory, tagging

I understand theory that is behind tagged pointers and how it is used to save additional data in pointer.
But i dont understand this part (from wikipedia article about tagged pointers).

> Most architectures are byte-addressable (the smallest addressable unit is a byte), but certain types of data will often be aligned to the size of the data, often a word or multiple thereof. This discrepancy leaves a few of the least significant bits of the pointer unused

Why is this happening ?
Does pointer have only 30 bites (on 32 bit architectures) and that 2 bites are result of aligning?
Why there are 2 bites left unused in first place ?
And does this decrease size of addresable space (from 2^32 bytes to 2^30 bytes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an architecture that uses 16-bit alignment and also 16-bit pointers (just to avoid having too many binary digits!). A pointer will only ever be referring to memory locations that are multiples of 16, but the pointer value is still precise down to the byte. So a pointer that, in binary, is:

`0000000000000100`

refers to the memory location 4 (the fifth byte in memory):

```
┌────────────────────┬───────────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Address in Decimal │ Address in Binary │ 8─bit bytes │ 16─bit words │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┤
│ 0                  │ 0000000000000000  │ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│ 1                  │ 0000000000000001  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ └──────────┘ │
│ 2                  │ 0000000000000010  │ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│ 3                  │ 0000000000000011  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ └──────────┘ │
│ 4 - this one       │ 0000000000000100  │ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│ 5                  │ 0000000000000101  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ └──────────┘ │
│ 6                  │ 0000000000000110  │ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│ 7                  │ 0000000000000111  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ └──────────┘ │
│ ...                │                   │             │              │
└────────────────────┴───────────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘
```

With 16-bit alignment, there will never be a pointer referring to memory location 5 because it wouldn't be aligned, the next useful value is 6:

`0000000000000110`

Note that the least significant bit (the one on the far right) is still 0. In fact, for **all** valid pointer values on that architecture, that bit will be 0. That's what they mean by leaving *"...a few of the least significant bits of the pointer unused."* In my example it's just one bit, but if you had 32-bit alignment, it would be **two** bits at the end of pointer value that would always be zero:

```
┌────────────────────┬───────────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Address in Decimal │ Address in Binary │ 8─bit bytes │ 32─bit words │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┤
│  0                 │ 0000000000000000  │ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│  1                 │ 0000000000000001  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│  2                 │ 0000000000000010  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│  3                 │ 0000000000000011  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ └──────────┘ │
│  4                 │ 0000000000000100  │ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│  5                 │ 0000000000000101  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│  6                 │ 0000000000000110  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│  7                 │ 0000000000000111  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ └──────────┘ │
│  8                 │ 0000000000001000  │ ┌─────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│  9                 │ 0000000000001001  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│ 10                 │ 0000000000001010  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ │          │ │
│ 11                 │ 0000000000001011  │ ┌─────────┐ │ │          │ │
│                    │                   │ └─────────┘ │ └──────────┘ │
│ ...                │                   │             │              │
└────────────────────┴───────────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i finally understand how it works.